# Use Font Style on HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fonts, kineticjs

I am trying to add text on a canvas using kinetic JS library. Kinetic JS Provides the `setFontStyle()` method to support the styles on fonts.

http://kineticjs.com/docs/symbols/Kinetic.Text.php#setFontStyle

According to the documentation It supports 'normal', 'italic', or 'bold'.
But what I do if I want to apply bold and Italic at once. Also I want to underline the text. How I can do in kinetic JS.

Isn't there anyone to tell me :'(

Comment: Not sure about Kinetic but in Fabric.js, you could do it with: `new fabric.Text('your text', { fontWeight: 'bold', 'fontStyle': 'italic', textDecoration: 'underline' })`. See [this article](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-2/) for more.

Comment: can't you apply multiple styles the same way as in with css classes? try setFontStyle('bold italic');

Comment: As for underlining, I think you'll have to create a line underneath the text, don't think kineticjs supports it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like EliteOctagon already mentioned, KineticJS does not support underlining text yet. This is mainly due to the fact that text-decoration (including underlining) isn't supported in the html canvas element.

To add (multiple) font styles, is relatively easy.
The most recommended way is by defining it at the initiation, like this:

```
var text = new Kinetic.Text({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    fontSize: 20,
    fontStyle: 'bold italic'
    fill: 'black',
});
```

If you need to set the font style differently at another time then initiation, you can use the method `setFontStyle()` like you mentioned. For instance like this:

```
var text = new Kinetic.Text();
text.setFontStyle('bold italic');
```